# Need to find a way to align a bar to the absolute bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css

I need to know how to align a bar to the *absolute* bottom of the screen. Whenever I try this, the bar just ends at the end of a body of text, and I don't want it to do that. And no, I don't want `position: fixed` because I don't want the bar to scroll on pages with long amounts of text.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your markup and styles please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel, take something like this:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Paste the few lines of CSS, follow the instructions for the structural elements, and you're done. Sticking a footer has always been a pain in the neck :)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `position:fixed` ???

http://jsfiddle.net/KfeKf/

Not sure why you mean by not wanting the bar to scroll.

Comment: I meant that I don't want the bar to stay while the page is scrolling, sorry.